# DataGridView not displaying a row after it is created

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I'm using Visual Studio 10 and I just created a Database using SQL Server CE. Within it, I made a table `CSLDataTable` and that automatically created a `CSLDataSet` & `CSLDataTableTableAdapter`.

The three variables were automatically created in my MainWindow.cs class:

- `cSLDataSet`
- `cSLDataTableTableAdapter`
- `cSLDataTableBindingSource`

I have added a `DataGridView` in my Form called `dataGridView` and datasource `cSLDataTableBindingSource`.

In my MainWindow(), I tried adding a row as a test:

```
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
CSLDataSet.CSLDataTableRow row = cSLDataSet.CSLDataTable.NewCSLDataTableRow();

  row.File_ = "file";
  row.Artist = "artist11";
  row.Album = "album";
  row.Save_Structure = "save";
  row.Sent = false;
  row.Error = true;
  row.Release_Format = "release";
  row.Bit_Rate = "bitrate..";
  row.Year = "year";
  row.Physical_Format = "format";
  row.Bit_Format = "bitformat";
  row.File_Path = "File!!path";
  row.Site_Origin = "what";

cSLDataSet.CSLDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
cSLDataSet.AcceptChanges();
cSLDataTableTableAdapter.Fill(cSLDataSet.CSLDataTable);
cSLDataTableTableAdapter.Update(cSLDataSet);

dataGridView.Refresh();
dataGridView.Update();
}
```

In regards to the DataSet methods I tried calling, I had been trying to find a "correct" way to interact with the adapter, dataset, and datatable to successfully show the row, but to no avail.

I'm rather new to using SQL Server CE Database, and read a lot of the MSDN sites & thought I was on the right track, but I've had no luck.

The `DataGridView` shows the headers correctly, but that new row does not show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to work by calling the `TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(DataSet)` method. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384426.aspx